# Strip Text When Mail Received In Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook 2010 talking to an Exchange Server (of which I have zero ability to influence change on), so this must be a client-side solution.

Anyway, I'm looking for a way to strip "garbage" text that is always added to the bottom of message I receive from certain domains.

For example,  I'll get something like this...

```
XXX: Sprocket, Cog [ABC] [123] [XYZ, 456]
```

All the stuff from the first '[' on is garbage to me and I want to get rid of it automatically on receipt by Outlook.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to create a macro that's triggered by mail coming in.

To get you started, Microsoft offers an example on catching this event in [KB292063 - "How to create a custom rule using Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) in Outlook 2002"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292063) (Still applicable to OL2010).

From there you'll want to use [VBScripts's RegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html) ([regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)) to do a Replace on the matching text pattern (replace the pattern with nothing/blank).

For example, using a regex search pattern of `\[.+\]` will find/match `[ABC] [123] [XYZ, 456]` in the given example string.  [This web-tool](http://www.tmehta.com/regexp/regexpfind.asp) will help you ensure your RegEx patterns are agreeable to VB's RegEx.

If you are new to VBA macros, perhaps check out MS' "[Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814736.aspx)".

If you have specific VBA programming questions as you go, check out [StackOverflow.com](http://www.StackOverflow.com).